# Inserting a range obtained from getRange in an importrange formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setFormula to insert an =IMPORTRANGE formula, based on a changing range. So far I have this:

```
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(j, 1, 8, 8);
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(frontPage.getRange(2, 8)); 

var cell = frontPage.getRange(1, 8);
 cell.setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1SrLVOfzRicpnBUl4U2x6-dfD4us0B6QTxfchkqS9U8w",\''+ rangeToCopy +'\')');
```

j is a variable I define elsewhere, and works fine if I use copyTo, but that needs refreshing, whereas IMPORTRANGE is more immediate.

However, the above script enters the following formula in the cell:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1SrLVOfzRicpnBUl4U2x6-dfD4us0B6QTxfchkqS9U8w",'Range')
```

So, I clearly need to replace 'Range' with an actual range of cells.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Am I understanding that the changing range is a text value such as "A2:C25" which is found in a cell in your spreadsheet?

Comment: IF the answer to my question is Yes, then you do not need a sript, but can simply reference the cell in your formula.  `=IMPORTRANGE("1SrLVOfzRicpnBUl4U2x6-dfD4us0B6QTxfchkqS9U8w",Sheet1!B1)`  will pull the Range from cell B1 on Sheet1.  In there you may put **Sheet2!A1:F**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rangeToCopy` is an **object** of [class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). What you want in your formula is a **string** with its notation, like "A3:D5". To get that, use [getA1Notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()):

```
'some string' + rangeToCopy.getA1Notation() + 'another string'
```

Comment: Amazing! Super simple. Thanks very much.